# How to check the range returned by Excel OFFSET function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset

I have the following excel function:

```
OFFSET(Foglio1!C1;S_1x-1;0;E_1x-S_1x+1;1)
```

If I want to check the returned range during debugging, say e.g. D6:F10, is there a way to explicitly show it?

**E_1x** and **S_1x** are user defined names of single cells in the formula above.

I have discovered some indirect ways to check it, but having a method that directly shows me "D6:F10" (in the example above) would be much more practical.
Thanks for the attention.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7

Comment: @GSerg Unfortunately the article does not answer my question. If the formula returns e.g. the range value D6:F10, the evaluation method gives #VALUE!, as for excel if I put a range in a cell it is an error. For example, if I put the above formula in the cell, say, G15, I get #VALUE!, But what I want to obtain is the range it represents!

Comment: The article discusses using the Excel built in formula evaluator rather than putting a formula in a different cell. You would evaluate the original formula with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formula to show you the range of that `OFFSET()` formula in a cell:

```
=LET(
    initial,A1,
    row_shift,3,col_shift,4,
    height,5,width,8,
    range,ADDRESS(ROW(initial)+row_shift,COLUMN(initial)+col_shift)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(initial)+row_shift+height,COLUMN(initial)+col_shift+width),
    range
)
```

using your starting range "Foglio1!C1" and variable names "S_1x" and "E_1x" that becomes:

```
=LET(
    initial,Foglio1!C1,
    row_shift,S_1x-1,col_shift,0,
    height,E_1x-S_1x+1,width,1,
    range,ADDRESS(ROW(initial)+row_shift,COLUMN(initial)+col_shift)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(initial)+row_shift+height,COLUMN(initial)+col_shift+width),
    range
)
```

Note 1: Apparently we use different punctuation for formulas. Make sure to use semicolon ; instead of comma , for separation.

Note 2: For this to work, the initial range has to be a single cell and the variables/parameters cannot be error values.

> Edit 1:

Without the use of the `LET()` function the formula can be written as follows, using your starting range "Foglio1!C1" and variable names "S_1x" and "E_1x":

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(Foglio1!C1)+(S_1x-1),COLUMN(Foglio1!C1)+(0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(Foglio1!C1)+(S_1x-1)+(E_1x-S_1x+1),COLUMN(Foglio1!C1)+(0)+(1))
```

This will show a range with absolute references, i.e. encapsulating the range letters and numbers with $, e.g. `$A$2:$M$9`.

Combine the above formula with the `SUBSTITUTE()` function to get rid of the $ symbol by replacing it with an empty string value ("")

Comment: I thank for the answer. I was actually expecting for something more simple but maybe it works. Unfortunately I cannot check it right now as LET is not a function of my Excel 2019...
And yes, I use semicolon instead of comma in my excel, it prevents errors with number formats!

Comment: Well, you can just replace the respective "variables" in the final calculation formula for the range. I'll edit the post to make it copy-paste-able

Comment: Ok Dattel, your Edit1 is an interesting workaround. I noticed however that for your formula to work fine column indexes have to be slightly corrected in this way:

=ADDRESS(ROW(Foglio1!C1)+(S_1x-1),COLUMN(Foglio1!C1))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(Foglio1!C1)+(S_1x-1)+(E_1x-S_1x),COLUMN(Foglio1!C1))

Comment: Still, I think that for making debug it would need to been even more simple, as having to split the original OFFSET formula into pieces to be able to apply your ADDRESS formula could lead to typing errors. The ideal solution would be to copy the original OFFSET formula and put it as the argument of some "RANGE" function able to return directly the range that the OFFSET function represents. But, at this point, I think that excel cannot do it with its native functions. I may consider to make a customized VBA function for this. Anyway thanks for your interest in my issue.